# Can a modern 1.44MB floppy drive work with an Amiga 2000?

Tags: amiga, floppy-disk

Can an Amiga 2000 (or even A500) be made to easily work with modern 1.44 MB drives?  Meaning, is it just a matter of pin mappings or are the drives just too incompatible?

I realize there are other solutions like GoTek but I'm interested in using real floppies.

Thanks.

Comment: I swear I searched for this question but didn't find it.  I guess I just put in the wrong search terms or something.